# White AppIcon displayed in Xcode 7 Project on simulator and on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

[image: White App Icon[1]]

As you can see even though I have added the AppIcons correctly to my Xcode7 project, I can see only white app icon. It is not default blank app icon. It is just white app. How can I fix this ? I have tried most of the stackoverflow answers.